# Modal Bottom Sheet scrim color is not shown in status bar in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

Migrating an app in view system to Jetpack compose.

The bottom sheet **scrim color is shown on the status bar** in the current app.
How to reproduce the same in Jetpack compose?

**Screenshot of the app using views**

[image]

**Screenshot of the app using compose**

[image]

**Compose Code**

```
val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
)
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
    sheetContent = {
        // Not relevant
    },
) {
    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        topBar = {
            // Not relevant
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        if (!modalBottomSheetState.isAnimationRunning) {
                            if (modalBottomSheetState.isVisible) {
                                modalBottomSheetState.hide()
                            } else {
                                modalBottomSheetState.show()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Add,
                    contentDescription = "Add",
                )
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
    ) { innerPadding ->
        // Not relevant - Nav graph code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Material3 you can provide the `windowInsets` to the ModalBottomSheet directly. You can either set them to 0 or keep which ones you prefer.

For example, if you only want the bottom insets to be maintained use this code:

```
ModalBottomSheet(
        sheetState = sheetState,
        onDismissRequest = {  },
        modifier = modifier,
        windowInsets = BottomSheetDefaults.windowInsets.only(WindowInsetsSides.Bottom),
    ) {
        // Bottom sheet layout 
    }
```

Comment: Saved my evening.. Works great for Compose Material3.

Answer (score 3):

try to use the [System UI Controller](https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/) in the [accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist/) library to control the statusBar Color and navigationBar color

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.18.0"
```

```
// Remember a SystemUiController
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
val useDarkIcons = MaterialTheme.colors.isLight

SideEffect {
    // Update all of the system bar colors to be transparent, and use
    // dark icons if we're in light theme
    systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
        color = Color.Transparent,
        darkIcons = useDarkIcons
    )

    // setStatusBarsColor() and setNavigationBarsColor() also exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove automatic insects and make status bar transparent:

```
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    window.statusBarColor = android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT;
```

Then draw your bottom sheet and it will go under all system bars including status bar

Just don't forget to add insects for the rest of the views when needed, it's in compose foundation now:

```
            modifier = Modifier
                                .navigationBarsPadding()
                                .captionBarPadding()
                                .imePadding()
                                .statusBarsPadding(),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ModalBottomSheet(
    modifier = Modifier
        .imePadding()
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight(0.95f),
    sheetState = sheetState,
    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
    scrimColor = Color(0x8A000000),
    dragHandle = {},
    windowInsets = WindowInsets(0,0,0,0),
    onDismissRequest = {
        scope.launch {
            sheetState.hide()
        }
    },
) {
    }
```

use androidx.compose.material3.ModalBottomSheet and set windowInsets = WindowInsets(0,0,0,0)

Comment: Setting the WindowInsets worked perfectly, thank you!! I don't understand why there are vertical insets set by default

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of Compose, there's a `statusBarColor` parameter that is set in the `Theme.kt` file by default. If you're not using accompanist, try altering that value to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem, I had done everything from doing edge to edge to making the status bar transparent but it was still not working but then I used `WindowInsets` parameter in `ModalBottomSheet` and it worked like charm.

Here's what worked for me:

```
ModalBottomSheet(onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest, sheetState = bottomSheetState, windowInsets = WindowInsets(0.dp)) {
    CountryList(onRowClicked = onRowClicked)
}
```