# How to apply the shadow to the status bar on opening a bottom sheet in Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to use Compose to apply the shadow that's applied to the background when you open a bottom sheet to the status bar as well, example here (Google News app). The whole background, including the status bar gets a shadow, but I can't replicate the same behaviour in a simple app. I've bee using the [`ModalBottomSheetLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#ModalBottomSheetLayout(kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material.ModalBottomSheetState,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0)) composable to invoke the bottom sheet.

[image: Google News app with a bottom sheet opened]

I've tried using the [accompanist library](https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/) and its System UI Controller to set the color of the status bar to `Transparent`, but maybe I'm misunderstanding what that's meant to do, as the status bar just remains white and unchanged when the bottom sheet is opened.

How can I put the status bar "in the background" as well when a bottom sheet is opened?

Comment: This is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69560253/9636037). But unfortunately, there is no correct answer there till now. 

Comment: Thanks @Abhimanyu! I actually raised [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/231606426) for this, because the view-based [BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment) applies the shadow to the status bar out of the box. I think it's missed functionality in the Compose one!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modal Bottom Sheet scrim color is not shown in status bar in Jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69560253/modal-bottom-sheet-scrim-color-is-not-shown-in-status-bar-in-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score 0):

There is a question asked before, but I will keep my old answer here as well.
[Modal Bottom Sheet scrim color is not shown in status bar in Jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69560253/modal-bottom-sheet-scrim-color-is-not-shown-in-status-bar-in-jetpack-compose/73887258#73887258)

Keeping here old answer as it may be relevant to somebody, new in a link above ^^

**Approach below is [Deprecated](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/), one above it not**

You need a dependency

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-insets:0.17.0"
```

put app content in `ProvideWindowInsets`

```
setContent {
    ProvideWindowInsets {
        AppContent()
    }
}
```

then add `Modifier.navigationBarsWithImePadding()` to the content of Bottom sheet like this

```
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetContent = { SheetContent(Modifier.navigationBarsWithImePadding()) },
    sheetState = sheetState,
    sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Black
) {}
```

Sample https://github.com/lbenevento/compose-modalbottomsheet

Comment: ProvideWindowInsets and navigationBarsWithImePadding is deprecated
so your answer is outdated. Please provide answer relevant to 2023.

Comment: Clarified - link to not deprecated answer is in first line.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for 2023:

```
    @Composable
    fun ModalStatusBarBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetContent: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit,
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        sheetState: ModalBottomSheetState =
            rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden),
        sheetShape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large,
        sheetElevation: Dp = ModalBottomSheetDefaults.Elevation,
        sheetBackgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
        sheetContentColor: Color = contentColorFor(sheetBackgroundColor),
        scrimColor: Color = ModalBottomSheetDefaults.scrimColor,
        content: @Composable () -> Unit
    ): Unit = ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetContent = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .navigationBarsPadding()
            ) {
                sheetContent.invoke(this@ModalBottomSheetLayout)
            }
        },
        modifier = modifier,
        sheetState = sheetState,
        sheetShape = sheetShape,
        sheetElevation = sheetElevation,
        sheetBackgroundColor = sheetBackgroundColor,
        sheetContentColor = sheetContentColor,
        scrimColor = scrimColor
    ) {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        var statusBarColor by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.Transparent) }
        val backgroundColor = remember {
            val typedValue = TypedValue()
            if (context.findActivity().theme
                    .resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.windowBackground, typedValue, true)
            ) {
                Color(typedValue.data)
            } else {
                sheetBackgroundColor
            }
        }
        
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(statusBarColor)
            .statusBarsPadding()) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .background(backgroundColor)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .navigationBarsPadding()) {
                content()
            }
        }

        DisposableEffect(Unit) {
            val window = context.findActivity().window
            val originalStatusBarColor = window.statusBarColor
            statusBarColor = Color(originalStatusBarColor)

            window.statusBarColor = TRANSPARENT
            WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

            onDispose {
                window.statusBarColor = originalStatusBarColor
                WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
ModalStatusBarBottomSheetLayout(
           sheetState = state,
           modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
           sheetContent = {
                Text(modifier = Modifier
                       .fillMaxWidth()
                       .height(250.dp), 
                     text = "BOTTOM SHEET CONTENT")
                }
    ) {
        Button(onClick = {
            scope.launch {
               state.show()
            }
        }) {
              Text(text = "SHOW BOTTOM SHEET")
           }
    }
```

Here is [`findActivity`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74696154/3278271) implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Call this in onCreate function;

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //Call this
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        setContent {

            AppTheme {

                MainScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's one way of achieving this, but I don't actually want my app to be full screen - the Google News app doesn't seem to be either.

Comment: you don't have to, you can easily set padding value from top with the status bar height. However you may not want this solution.